# Проблема при использовании плагина Saphali Woocommerce Russian

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой, если отключить ненужные поля в форме заказа используя **Saphali Woocommerce Russian**, то форма перестает работать, не видит варианты доставки.

Если отключаю обязательное заполнение поля адрес в functions.php, все равно заказ не оформляется, требует заполнить поле адреса

```
$fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['required'] = false;
$fields['billing']['billing_city']['required'] = false;
$fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['required'] = false;
$fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['required'] = false;
```

[Скрин](https://prnt.sc/jfo5tk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде решил проблему, правда не самый лучший способ, но по-другому пока не получается.
Проблема чаще всего проявляется, когда отключаешь отображение полей. Поэтому пришлось отключить обязательное заполнение, поля скрыть стилями. Повторюсь, не самый лучший и правильный вариант, но пока работает. Если есть лучше способ (проверенный), предлагайте, не стесняйтесь.